# bypass killswitch on lg16c?

Tags: password

I am trying to factory reset a recycled Lg16c phone, but it has killswitch. Is there a default or master password to bypass this lick?

Comment: What kind of kill-switch is it?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEh2VpbNj_c

> A freshly reset LG phone (like most other Android devices these days)
>   will ask for the Google account it was used with previously. You can
>   bypass by going into accessibility settings and adding a button combo
>   for triggering overview. Then, you use the talkback settings to open a
>   web browser, which lets you download an APK from& RootJunky that
>   basically just opens the system settings. Because you added an
>   overview button combo, you can use that to access
>   overview/multi-window and install the APK. Once you're in settings,
>   you can add a new user, gain access to the full device, then switch
>   back to the owner account and reset without protection. The video
>   above gives the full rundown.

Source: http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/01/12/lgs-factory-reset-protection-can-be-bypassed-in-mere-minutes/